# Change count into an array of letters, python

Tags: python

I am struggling with an idea I want put into a python script. I'm not even sure how to ask the most appropriate question as I've been surfing through the net trying to find what I want with no luck.

Basically, I have a script that does a simple calculation:

```
divider = int(math.ceil(df.scale / 3000))
```

This is because I want ' divider' to return the value divided by 3000 and always rounded up. I want to use that value to help me return letters.

So, it goes like this:

if 1 returns then I want a to return 'A'
if 2 returns, then I want to create 'A', 'B'
if 3 returns, then I want to create 'A', 'B', 'C'
and so on....

My end result is, that I want to save some files. 'divider' will determine how many files I want to save and then each file will recursively be named with the letter in it (i.e. FileA, FileB, FileC...)

Ok, I know my question isn't exactly well put together, but I'm struggling with the logic, so if you need some clarity, please let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
for i in range(int(math.ceil(df.scale / 3000))):
  # i will contain 0, 1, 2, ...
  # letter will contain 'A', 'B', 'C', ...
  letter = chr(ord('A') + i)
```

Or if you need the actual list:

```
[chr(ord('A') + i) for i in range(int(math.ceil(df.scale / 3000)))]
```

You can also use [`string.ascii_uppercase`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase) for a list of uppercase letters and slice it as you need:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

print list(ascii_uppercase)[:int(math.ceil(df.scale / 3000))]
```

Comment: Niklas. Thanks for interpreting my gibberish question and coming up with exactly what I had in mind!

Answer (score 3):

Because it's the end of the day for me, here's another approach which generalizes to more than 26 files, spreadsheet-column-name style:

```
import string, itertools

def name_generator(min_length=1, alphabet=string.ascii_uppercase):
    for length in itertools.count(min_length):
        for chars in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=length):
            yield ''.join(chars)

def get_names(n):
    return list(itertools.islice(name_generator(), 0, n))
```

which gives

```
>>> get_names(1)
['A']
>>> get_names(3)
['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> get_names(30)
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD']
```

Comment: Thanks DSM. I like the define function approach. I had thought about using one when trying to calculate my end result and I still just might do that.